# How do I run a 'Debug' in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've added some code to the `AppDelegate.m` file in my React Native app. I hoped this code would be run in the Xcode console when I clicked "Build", but it doesn't. However, I did come across this

[image]

When I look at the logs from the "Debug" here on 2019-11-21, I do see the output of the code I want to see. I don't know how this Debug was run though. Does anyone know how I can run it again?

Comment: If you are using some sort of version maintenance tool you can revert back to the previous version or you can see this error in issue navigator hold Cmd+5

Comment: Debug just means run. This was the console output the last time you ran your app.

Comment: matt you can put this as an answer if you want.
SouravSachdeva this is good advice, thanks!

Comment: Actually, to be precise, the output in the console is the output produced by the _selected_ run  in the Report Navigator (the entries with ▶︎ as seen in your screenshot)